# Respond to an http request from another machine node js

Tags: node.js, http

Situation :
A Load Balancer has say 2 machines A and B behind it. Suppose machine A receives the request from the client via the load balancer and passes the message to a queue whose consumer is a micro service. The micro service does its work and makes a json message. This json message is to be sent back back to the client.

Current Implementation :
The micro service sends back the json message it created to the queue between machine A and the micro service. The server id is passed in the message to the micro service by which it knows which queue to publish the message to. So basically there are queues between the micro service and every machine behind the load balancer.

Problem :
With growing traffic the number of machines is increasing and so is the number of queues between the micro service and the machine which is a headache. Is there a way to respond to a request from Machine B which was received on Machine A? I do not know how the context be maintained. Somebody suggested Redis but is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you care about context between Service A and Service B, but you've decided to use a distributed queue of some sort, can you elaborate on which queue implementation are you using? (RabbitMQ perhaps?)

Is there a need for keeping the context? If you can restructure the application such that there is no need to keep the context or that you can pass the "context id" from Service A and Service B back and forth then there is no need to have it strongly coupled, which by definition is why you'd want microservices.

You'd be able to scale them horizontally without in a decoupled manner.

If you do still need to communicate in a synchronous way then queueing might not be the easy way to go.

I'd suggest some sort of an RPC implementation between Service A and Service B, take a look at gRPC, https://github.com/grpc/grpc.github.io/blob/master/docs/tutorials/basic/node.md, or if it's too complex you can just have a private HTTP based API no both machines and communicate internally inside your cluster.

Good luck.

Comment: Yes the pub/sub is RabbitMQ. By context I meant, there is a response object corresponding a request in Nodejs. So basically how could server B respond to a server A's request.
Internal API on so many machines looks kind of messy.

Comment: what do you suggest @gmaliar